# PySpark: Spark Dataframe - Convert ImageSchema Column to a nDArray as a new column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am reading images(*.jpg) in a folder as to a spark dataframe using the ImageSchema.

```
image_df = spark.read.format("image").load("/mnt/train/*", inferschema=True)
```

- Most of the DeepLearning algorithms expect the images to be an nDArray. How to do this conversion in a dataframe itself? Is this to be done using an udf?
- I see that there is are some to ndArray functions in MMLSpark that was integrated in [spark 2.4](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/12/10/introducing-built-in-image-data-source-in-apache-spark-2-4.html), anyone used this?
  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out myself, below solution could help someone.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType,IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
import numpy as np

def to_np_array(x):    
  height = 200
  width  = 200
  nChannels = 3
  return np.reshape(x, (height,width,nChannels)).tolist()
spark_to_np_array = udf(to_np_array, ArrayType(ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType()))))

imagesdf = spark.read.format("image").load("/mnt/images/*", inferschema=True)
imagesdf = imagesdf.withColumn("FileName", regexp_replace('image.origin', 'dbfs:/mnt/images/', '')) 
imagesdf = imagesdf.withColumn("ImageArray", spark_to_np_array(imagesdf["image.data"])).select("FileName","ImageArray")
```

[image: The Resulting Schema looks like this]